# JQuery replace onClick in h:commandLink

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, xhtml

What I am trying to do is replace a on click with JQuery.

< h:commandLink onClick="hi" value="Button"/>

to

< h:commandLink onClick="function(hi)" value="Button" />

Is it possible to select inside a command with JQuery? And more specifically can you do it with JSF tags?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is the answer.

```
$( ".class" ).attr('onclick', 'whatever I want it to be');
```

So you can do it this way.

```
<h:commandLink class='btn' onClick="hi" value="Button"/>
var text = $('.btn').attr('onclick');

$('.btn').attr('onclick', "function("+text+")");
```

Take it a bit further and do it for every button on the screen.

```
$('.btn').each(function () {
      var text = $(this).attr('onclick');

      $(this).attr('onclick', "function("+text+")");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the button an `id` or `class` and call a `click()` function on it.

**EDIT**

```
$( ".class" ).click(function() {  //Or #id
    //Do work
});
```

This way any element with that `class` or `id` will call that function, it still works like an `onClick` event

Comment: Yeah this is easy to do but I already have over 100 buttons and I have people who will develop more buttons that they will not add the correct ID or a ID/class at all. So what I was hoping is there a way to select the h:commandLink onClick.

Comment: Experiment by looking at your source code to see how the jsf tags render in html. Maybe that will give you a lead.

Comment: So if I had a specific class on these buttons how would i use it? Because I need to be able to get the info in onClick first. so that i can wrap my function around the text.

Comment: Yeah but is it possible to get the onClick that is already in there? By this I mean. button onclick='someFn()' then when your function runs i want to be able to check if something is true or false. If it is true then run the onClick in that button. Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks :) Edit--- Let me put an example. < h:commandLink class='button' onClick="hi()" value="Button"/> $(".class").click(function(){ if(someFunctionDontWorryAbout)then do onClick or in this case the do hi();{});

Comment: You lost me, sorry! :(

Comment: Hmmmm Its hard to explain lol. Well how about this. Is it possible to get the onClick text from a button that has a class and set that text to a var? Then Modify that onClick to whatever I want?

Comment: innerHTML() in jquery? I'm just taking some shots in the dark now. :P

Answer (score -1):

To select on a namespaced attribute you can use a filter.   Here's a demo using your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/fBv4q/

```
$('button').filter(function() { return typeof $(this).attr('h:commandlink') != 'undefined'; }).attr('onclick','alert(111)').html('Modified onClick');
```

The 'undefined' check is important because your attribute doesn't have a value, but it still exists.

And rather than supplying a function call as a string, look into using jQuery's "on" method to attach the event